# gif image is not created by imagecreatefromstring() and imagegif()

Tags: php, image, file, file-io

I am developing an api that accepets image file in base64 encoded form from the mobile app.

Now the apis task to create that image file and store in server.

below is the code.

```
<?php 

$file="mygif_image.gif";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if(!filesize($file)){
    echo "corrupted file.."; die;
}

$image_contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
fclose($handle);

$encoded_data = base64_encode($image_contents);
/* assume that this $encoded_data I am getting in api as request */

/* this will be the server side code, where encoded data is accepted and 
   I required to store image in server*/

$image_binary_content = base64_decode($encoded_data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($image_binary_content);

if ($im !== false) {
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($im,"mygif_image2.gif");
imagedestroy($im);
}else{
    echo "some thing went wrong..";
}
?>
```

The image is getting stored properly at required place, issue is effects are not comming.

imagejpeg(), imagepng() such functions work very nice in case of jpg,joeg,png files.

Don't know which is the place, where something is going wrong ??

Comment: which effects you want to give? and where?

Comment: What do you mean by "issue is effects are not comming"?

Comment: I mean that in gif file, some animations are always there

when I run this code, It creates same kind of image file, but animation effects which are in origional image file, that are not available in newly created file..

for more clarification you open both the files, say original and newly created one..

you will get difference between both.

Comment: Please check both files code.. i mean compare code of both file new and old one...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not realy clear, I think you like to know why you script is working for jpg and png files, but dos an `echo "some thing went wrong.."` for gif files.

If your `imagecreatefromstring` only failes for your gif files, this could mean that the content of this files is a image format that php supports.

this can have different reasons:

1. Your gif File content is corrupted or was not read correctly
2. Your file is no real gif image (Maybe its an other imageformat e.g. bmp that was renamed to .gif)
3. It is a valid gif file, but contains more than 1 image frame (e.g. animated gif files)

Comment: in php manual(http://in2.php.net/function.imagecreatefromstring) it is specifeied that imagecreatefromstring() function is for jpg, jpeg, gif, png etc files

Comment: I know, but a file with extension .gif could also contain diffent data.

Often people rename yust files without realy convert them, so it coul be, that a .bmp file is renamed to .gif. In this case imagecreatefromstring would not support this.

And i don`t now exactly what happens for multi-frame gif-Files in imagecreatefromstring.

I yust know that 'imagegif()' only supports single frame gif-files.

Comment: Hi Radon, I downloaded that file from internet, and then tested this scrupt.

but thanks for sharing this information.